# Selenium testing machine

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, continuous-integration, htmlunit, ui-testing

--- **TL;DR**

At this point I suggest everyone to tied their Continuous Integration server/service to https://ghostinspector.com/

**OLD QUESTION**

after three days googling and testing I gave up, and I need help.

My objective is allow my co-workers to record one or more tests with Selenium IDE. Export them, upload them into a server, and get this server running these tests using the webdriver with htmlunit. As we build or fix the app, we will upload the tests to make out test library.

Record a test with Selenium IDE is okay. But getting it running is the problem. The machine we intend to let the tests is an linux amazon server. No front-end stuff, no kde, gtk, so no firefox, chrome, etc... This is why I've specified the htmlunit driver.

So far I wasn't able to get this task running even into my machine - Ubuntu 12.04 x86_64.

I downloaded the selenium-server tarball, and tried running:

```
java -jar selenium-server.jar -htmlSuite "*webdriver" "our.site.org" "/path/to/testsuite1.html" "/path/to/report1.html"
```

No success. Even changing the "*webdriver" (using other pops-up a browser screen).

I've tried running the server and the standalone server and connecting via browser.

I've tried PHP bindings by facebook.

I've tried PHPUnit and Testing Selenium classes - along with their respectives exported scripts from Selenium Formatters.

I really do not know where I'm slipping. Can anyone give me a safe direction, tutorial, etc, to follow with?

--- **EDIT**

Okay, my question may be resumed to:

What si the command line that would allow me to run selenese scripts with selenium-server, using the HtmlUnit driver?

Comment: Why not use Selenium WebDriver instead?

Comment: Using the plain webdriver needs you to have the browsers installed - option I discarded, since it is just a really headless server - or, using HtmlUnit which requires selenium-server to be installed.

Comment: I do most of my automated scripts using only HTML driver, no need for a browser tbh. And you're going to need the server either way.

Comment: @aimbire would you like to answer with the how I can use the htmlunit driver? I still couldn't find out how to do it.

Comment: No problem, just hope it helps. I found that HTML Driver can't understand some JavaScript in the pages i test, so i keep them for the simple tests.

Comment: Have you tried the WebDriver+Xvfb approach? My Jenkins runs acceptance tests in JRuby with gems watir-webdriver (which is based on selenium-webdriver) and headless (which leverages an Xvfb session): I'm quite sure you could do something similar.

Comment: @Vincent I'm using that approach currently. Xvfb + webdriver + firefox to run selenese tests. But I'm trying to figure out how to run the tests without firefox and xvfb; using htmlunit instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read this blog post by David Burns (Automated Tester):

http://www.theautomatedtester.co.uk/tutorials/selenium/selenium_rc_setup.htm

He describes the way to run selenese tests using HTMLSuite.

> We are going to use the HTMLSuite commands of the Selenium Remote
>   Control. This allows you run your Selenese Test Suites as is. The
>   command should look like java -jar selenium-servre.jar -htmlsuite
>       . Browser
>   could be : -*firefox
>                                   -*chrome
>                                   -*iexplore
>                                   -*iehta
>                                   -*safari
>                                   -*custom /path/to/browser
>
> The path to the test suite and the results file should be a full path.
>
> Here is an example command; java -jar selenium-server.jar  -htmlsuite
>   *iexplore http://www.theautomatedtester.co.uk c:\testsuite\testsuite.html c:\testsuite\results.html

I would point out that htmlunit does not seem to be a supported option so I would expect to use -*custom and provide a path to htmlunit.

This is legacy functionality so there is a chance it doesn't work as expected any more.  HTMLSuite expects the tests to be in Selenese (HTML table) format, you mention trying with the PHP binding, I would not expect this to work.  If you do want to use some PHP bindings I would suggest using Adam Saunter's fork of the facebook bindings, they are the most up to date and best supported.

https://github.com/Element-34/saunter.php

Comment: I already have the selenese testing machine installed into a EC2 Amazon AMI-based instance, running tests with Firefox 19. The question is really about how to run those with HtmlUnit.

Comment: To quote the above: "I would point out that htmlunit does not seem to be a supported option so I would expect to use -*custom and provide a path to htmlunit."

Answer (score 4):

Are you using Continuous Integration?
If so, you should consider getting a plugin to have your CI software run the Selenium tests. Works like a charm for me with Jenkins.

Considering your particular setup, you could both have the amazon linux server run the tests with HTMLUnitDriver, and declare other machines (with a GUI and proper browser) as "nodes" to run your test on other browsers.

[Link to a tutorial](http://centripetal.ca/blog/2011/02/07/getting-started-with-selenium-and-jenkins/)

Comment: Thx for your reply. We are studying how and when implement the CI here in the company, but it's not gonna happen for a while. The link you sent is cool, really cool, but my question right now is: how can I run that command line using htmlunit driver instead of firefox driver? There is no option *htmlunit option.

Answer (score 0):

With Selenium WebDriver you can point to start a HtmlUnit in a already started node

In Java you'll do something like this:

```
IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.HtmlUnit());
```

To start the node just make sure to set browserName to 'htmlunit'.

Comment: @aimbirre, yeah, I know this approach too. But I'm avoiding to code anything. I need to keep the tests as much as selenese as possible in my current task. This is a limitation I can't override right now here.